# PHP does not receive parameters from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to call PHP script that change some content of HTML file.

First, I have HTML with a button. When I click this button, it call a javascript function which will post some parameters to PHP script. This script will take the parameters and generate the content that will be displayed in the HTML.

1) First, I were have form tag that send post action to the php. I delete this form tag from the HTML.

2) Then, I call jsFunction() "javascript function" when clicking "Run" button in the HTML.

```
onclick="jsFunction();"
```

3) I create javascript function:

```
jsFunction(){
    var url = "calculateResult.php";
    var params = "querySeq=querySeq&program=program&patientIDarray=patientIDarray&blast_flag=blast_flag";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             // change the content of the div in second tab
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", url+"?"+params, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

4) PHP file send replay to the javascript via echo statement.

Now, I think PHP does not receive any parameters from the javascript function!

Is there something wrong in my code?

**Edit 1:**

One of the steps in the php is generate text file and put one of the parameters "querySeq" in that file. When I open the file, it is empty.

The PHP file:

```
<?php

include("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/js-i2b2/cells/plugins/examples/BLAST/assets/include/path.inc");

$jobid = (empty($_GET['jobid'])) ? '' : $_GET['jobid'];
$blastdb = (empty($_POST['blastdb'])) ? '' : $_POST['blastdb'];
$blastpath = (empty($_POST['blastpath'])) ? '' : $_POST['blastpath'];
$patientIDarray = (empty($_POST['patientIDarray'])) ? '' : $_POST['patientIDarray'];
$opt = (empty($_GET['opt'])) ? '' : $_GET['opt'];
$blast_flag = (empty($_POST['blast_flag'])) ? 1 : $_POST['blast_flag'];
$filter_flag = (empty($_POST['filter_flag'])) ? '' : $_POST['filter_flag'];
$filt_val = (empty($_POST['filt_val'])) ? '' : $_POST['filt_val'];
$cutoffType = (empty($_POST['cutoffType'])) ? '' : $_POST['cutoffType'];
$pct_cutoff = (empty($_POST['pct_cutoff'])) ? '' : $_POST['pct_cutoff'];
$blst_cutoff = (empty($_POST['blst_cutoff'])) ? '' : $_POST['blst_cutoff'];
$searchType = (empty($_POST['searchType'])) ? '' : $_POST['searchType'];
$program = (empty($_POST['program'])) ? '' : $_POST['program'];
$dot = (empty($_GET['dot'])) ? '' : $_GET['dot'];
$querySeq = (empty($_POST['querySeq'])) ? '' : $_POST['querySeq'];
$blastagainstfile = (empty($_FILES['blastagainstfile']['name'])) ? '' : $_FILES['blastagainstfile']['name'];
$alignmentView = (empty($_GET['alignmentView'])) ? '' : $_GET['alignmentView'];

if ($blast_flag == 1) {
    $jobid = time().rand(10, 99);
}
if (!$blast_flag && !$jobid) {
    echo "<p>Error: No job submitted.</p>"; 
    footer();
    exit;
}

if ($searchType == 'advanced') {
    $expect=(empty($_POST['expect'])) ? 10 : $_POST['expect'];
    $wordSize = (empty($_POST['wordSize'])) ? '' : $_POST['wordSize'];
    $targetSeqs = (empty($_POST['targetSeqs'])) ? '' : $_POST['targetSeqs'];
    $mmScore = (empty($_POST['mmScore'])) ? '' : $_POST['mmScore'];
    $matrix = (empty($_POST['matrix'])) ? '' : $_POST['matrix'];
    $gapCost = (empty($_POST['gapCost'])) ? '' : $_POST['gapCost']; 
    $filter = (empty($_POST['filter'])) ? 'F' : $_POST['filter'];
    $softMask = (empty($_POST['softMask'])) ? 'F' : $_POST['softMask'];
    $lowerCaseMask = (empty($_POST['lowerCaseMask'])) ? 'F' : $_POST['lowerCaseMask'];
    $ungapAlign = (empty($_POST['ungapAlign'])) ? 'F' : $_POST['ungapAlign'];
    $alignmentView = (empty($_POST['outFmt'])) ? 0 : $_POST['outFmt'];  
    $geneticCode = (empty($_POST['qCode'])) ? '' : $_POST['qCode'];
    $dbGeneticCode = (empty($_POST['dbCode'])) ? '' : $_POST['dbCode'];
    $otherParam = (empty($_POST['OTHER_ADVANCED'])) ? '' : $_POST['OTHER_ADVANCED'];    
    if ($otherParam) {
        if (!preg_match("/^\s+$/", $otherParam) && !preg_match("/^\s*\-[A-Za-z]/", $otherParam)) {
            echo "Error: The other advanced options must start with \"-\"";
            exit;
        }
    }   
    $advanceParam = "$expect!#%$wordSize!#%$targetSeqs!#%$mmScore!#%$matrix!#%$gapCost!#%$filter!#%$softMask!#%$lowerCaseMask!#%$ungapAlign!#%$alignmentView!#%$geneticCode!#%$dbGeneticCode!#%$otherParam";
}else {
    $advanceParam = "";
}

if (!$alignmentView) {
    $alignmentView = 0;
}

if($blast_flag == 1) {
    $nlstr = chr(10);
    $crstr = chr(13);

    if($querySeq || !preg_match("/^\s+$/", $querySeq)) {
        @ $fp1=fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.blastinput.txt", "w",1);
        if (!$fp1)
        {
            echo "<p><strong> Error: couldn't open $dataPath/$jobid.blastinput.txt </strong></p></body></html>";
            exit;
        }

        fwrite($fp1, $querySeq);
        fclose($fp1);
    }else {
        echo "<p style='color: red'>Error: please enter your query sequence or upload your fasta sequence file.</p><br>";
        exit;
    }




}

if($cutoffType == 'pct') {
    $criterion = $pct_cutoff;
}
if($cutoffType == 'blst') {
    $criterion = $blst_cutoff;
}

if(!$opt || $opt == 'wait') {
    $progressdot = "image/progressdot.png";
    echo "<p><strong>Your job is being processed ";
    for($i = 0; $i <= ($dot%6); $i++) {
        echo "<img src='$progressdot'>";
    }
    echo "</strong></p>";
    $dot += 1;
    echo "<p>Your job id is $jobid.</p>";
    echo "<p>Please wait here to watch the progress of your job.</p>";
    echo "<p>This page will update itself automatically until search is done.</p>";     
}

if(!$opt || $opt == 'wait') {
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" 
    content=\"10;URL=blastresult.php?jobid=$jobid&alignmentView=$alignmentView&opt=wait&dot=$dot\">";
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"expires\" 
          CONTENT=\"now\">";
}

if($blast_flag == 1) {  
    $blastagainst = "";
    if ($program == "blastn" || $program == "tblastn" || $program == "tblastx") {
        $dbPath = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/db/nucleotide";
    }else {
        $dbPath = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/db/protein";
    }

    if($blastagainstfile) {
        $blastagainst = "$dataPath/$jobid.blastagainst.txt";
    }

    if ($patientIDarray) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($patientIDarray); $i++) {
            $blastagainst .= " $dbPath/$patientIDarray[$i]";            
        }
    }
    $blastpath = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/blast/bin";
    $basicParam = "$jobid\t$searchType\t$blastagainst\t$program\t$blastpath";

    /*create child process to run perl script which do the blast search and write output data to apropriate files*/
    /* For windows */
    pclose(popen("start /b perl blast.pl \"$basicParam\" \"$advanceParam\"", "r"));
}


/* error log if there is error in BLAST */
$errFile = "$dataPath/$jobid.err";
/* parent process continue here to check child process done or not */
$filename = "$dataPath/$jobid.blaststring.txt";
if (file_exists($errFile) && filesize($errFile) > 0) {
    if(!$opt || $opt == 'wait') {
        echo "<script LANGUAGE=JavaScript>";
        echo "location.replace('blastresult.php?jobid=$jobid&opt=none')";
        echo "</script>";
    }else {
        echo "<p>There is error in executing BLAST. Following is the error message:<p>";
        $fperr = fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.err", "r");
        if(!$fperr) {
            echo "<p><strong> $jobid.err error: $errors  </strong></p></body></html>";
            exit;
        }

        while (!feof($fperr))
        {
            $line = rtrim(fgets($fperr)); 
            echo "$line<br>";
        }
        fclose($fperr);
    }   
}elseif(file_exists($filename)) {
    if ($alignmentView) {
        echo "<script LANGUAGE=JavaScript>";
        echo "location.replace('data/$jobid.blast')";
        echo "</script>";
    }else {
        if($blast_flag == 'Parse again') {
            $print_flag = 0;
            $cutoff_count = 0;

            @ $fpout=fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.par", "r");
            if (!$fpout)
            {
                echo "<p><strong> $jobid.par error: $phperrormsg  </strong></p></body></html>";
                exit;
            }

            @ $fpout3 = fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.out.par", "w", 1);
            if(!$fpout3) {
                echo "<p><strong> $jobid.out.par error: $errors  </strong></p></body></html>";
                exit;
            }

            while (!feof($fpout))
            {
                $fpout2_str = '';
                $line = rtrim(fgets($fpout));
                if (!$line) {
                    continue;
                }
                list($page, $query_name, $match_name, $score, $identities, $percentage, $e_value, $link) = preg_split("/\t/", $line);

                if($cutoffType == 'pct') {
                    $subject = $percentage;
                }else {
                    $subject = $score;
                }

                if($subject >= $criterion) {
                    fwrite($fpout3, "$page\t$query_name\t$match_name\t$score\t$identities\t$percentage\t$e_value\t$link\n");
                    $cutoff_count++;
                }
            }

            fclose ($fpout);
            fclose($fpout3);

            @ $fp = fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.blastcount.txt", "w", 1);
            if(!$fp) {
                echo "<p><strong> error: $php_errormsg  </strong></p></body></html>";
                exit;
            }else {
                fwrite($fp, "$cutoff_count\n");
            }

            fclose($fp);
        }

        $filename = "$dataPath/$jobid.blastcount.txt";

        while(!file_exists($filename)) {}

        if(!$opt || $opt == 'wait') {
            echo "<script LANGUAGE=JavaScript>";
            echo "location.replace('blastresult.php?jobid=$jobid&opt=none')";
            echo "</script>";
        }else {
            @ $fp = fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.blastcount.txt", "r");
            if(!$fp) {
                echo "<p><strong> error: $php_errormsg  </strong></p></body></html>";
                exit;
            }

            if(!feof($fp)) {
                $cutoff_count = fgets($fp);
            }
            fclose($fp);

            @ $fp = fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.blaststring.txt", "r");
            if(!$fp) {
                echo "<p><strong> error: $php_errormsg  </strong></p></body></html>";
                exit;
            }

            if(!feof($fp)) {
                $blastagainststring = rtrim(fgets($fp));
            }
            fclose($fp);

            if($cutoff_count == 0) {
                echo "<p>No comparison meets cutoff criterion. Please change expect value to blast again.</p>";
            }else {
                echo "<p><a href=data/$jobid.blast1.html target='_blank'>Inspect BLAST output</a><br>";         
                echo "<form action='blastresult.php?jobid=$jobid&opt=$opt' method='post'>";     
                echo "<p>Filter current page by score:</p>";
                echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Show <select name='filt_val'>";
                echo "<option value='0' selected>- All -";
                echo "<option value='1'>Top score";
                echo "<option value='5'>Top 5 scores";
                echo "<option value='10'>Top 10 scores";
                echo "</select> for each query sequence <input type='submit' name='filter_flag' value='Filter'></font></p>";                
                echo "<p>Re-parse current blast results (please select cutoff criterion):</p>";
                echo "<p><table style='font-size: 12px'>";
                echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' checked name='cutoffType' value='pct'>Similarity percentage</td><td></td>";
                echo "<td>Cutoff %: </td><td><input type='text' name='pct_cutoff' value=95 size=6 maxlength=6></td></tr>";              
                echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='cutoffType' value='blst'>Blast score</td><td></td>";        
                echo "<td>Cutoff score: </td><td><input type='text' name='blst_cutoff' value=1000 size=6 maxlength=6></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='submit' name='blast_flag' value='Parse again'>";             
                echo "</td></tr></table></p>";
                echo "</form>";     
                echo "<form action='sequence.php?jobid=$jobid' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit=\"return checkform(this);\">";
                echo "<p>Retrieve and download subject sequences in FASTA format:</p>";     
                echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='dldseq' value='all'>  Check here to download All sequences... ";
                echo "OR select particular sequences of interest below</p>";    
                echo "<p><input type='submit' value='Submit'> your selection of sequences to download</p>"; 
                echo "<p><table border = 1 style='font-size:10px' width=100% class='sortable'>";
                echo "<thead><tr align='center'><th>Query</th><th>Subject</th><th>Score</th><th>Identities (Query length)</th><th>Percentage</th><th>Expect</th></tr></thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                @ $fp = fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.download.txt", "w", 1) or die("Cannot open file: $jobid.download.txt");

                if($blast_flag == 'Parse again' || ($opt == 'none' && !$filter_flag)) {
                    @ $fpout3=fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.out.par", "r");
                    if(!$fpout3) {
                        echo "<p><strong> error: $php_errormsg  </strong></p></body></html>";
                        exit;
                    }
                    $i = 0;
                    $queryName = $preQueryName = "";
                    while(!feof($fpout3)) {
                        $row = fgets($fpout3);
                        if (!$row) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $element = preg_split("/\t/", $row);        
                        $page = $element[0];
                        $queryName = $element[1];
                        $target_name = $element[7];
                        $var_target = $page."\t".$element[1]."\t".$element[2];
                        if(count($element) != 1) {
                            if($queryName == $preQueryName) {
                                $i++;
                            }else {
                                $i = 0;
                            }

                            if($i < 10) {
                                echo "<tr align='center'><td>$element[1]</td><td align=left><input type='checkbox' id='checkedSeq' name='target[]' value='$var_target'>$target_name</td><td><a href=data/$jobid.blast$page.html#$element[1]$element[2] target='_blank'>$element[3]</a></td><td>$element[4]</td><td>$element[5]</td><td>$element[6]</td></tr>";
                                fwrite($fp, "$var_target\n");
                            }                   
                        }
                        $preQueryName = $queryName;
                    }
                    fclose($fpout3);
                }

                if($filter_flag == 'Filter')
                {
                    @ $fpout3=fopen("$dataPath/$jobid.out.par", "r");
                    if(!$fpout3) {
                        echo "<p><strong> error: $php_errormsg  </strong></p></body></html>";
                        exit;
                    }
                    $i = 0;
                    while(!feof($fpout3)) {
                        $row = fgets($fpout3);
                        if (!$row) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $element = preg_split("/\t/", $row);
                        $page = $element[0];
                        $target_name = $element[7];
                        $var_target = $page."\t".$element[1]."\t".$element[2];
                        if(count($element) != 1) {
                            if($filt_val != 0) {
                                if($i == 0) {
                                    $query_name = $element[1];
                                    echo "<tr align='center'><td>$element[1]</td><td align=left><input type='checkbox' id='checkedSeq' name='target[]' value='$var_target'>$target_name</td><td><a href=data/$jobid.blast$page.html#$element[1]$element[2] target='_blank'>$element[3]</a></td><td>$element[4]</td><td>$element[5]</td><td>$element[6]</td></tr>";
                                    fwrite($fp, "$var_target\n");
                                    $i++;
                                }elseif($query_name == $element[1] && $i < $filt_val) {
                                    echo "<tr align='center'><td>$element[1]</td><td align=left><input type='checkbox' id='checkedSeq' name='target[]' value='$var_target'>$target_name</td><td><a href=data/$jobid.blast$page.html#$element[1]$element[2] target='_blank'>$element[3]</a></td><td>$element[4]</td><td>$element[5]</td><td>$element[6]</td></tr>";
                                    fwrite($fp, "$var_target\n");
                                    $i++;
                                }elseif($query_name != $element[1]) {
                                    echo "<tr align='center'><td>$element[1]</td><td align=left><input type='checkbox' id='checkedSeq' name='target[]' value='$var_target'>$target_name</td><td><a href=data/$jobid.blast$page.html#$element[1]$element[2] target='_blank'>$element[3]</a></td><td>$element[4]</td><td>$element[5]</td><td>$element[6]</td></tr>";
                                    $query_name = $element[1];
                                    fwrite($fp, "$var_target\n");
                                    $i=1;
                                }
                            }else {
                                echo "<tr align='center'><td>$element[1]</td><td align=left><input type='checkbox' id='checkedSeq' name='target[]' value='$var_target'>$target_name</td><td><a href=data/$jobid.blast$page.html#$element[1]$element[2] target='_blank'>$element[3]</a></td><td>$element[4]</td><td>$element[5]</td><td>$element[6]</td></tr>";
                                fwrite($fp, "$var_target\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($fpout3);
                }
                fclose($fp);
                echo "</tbody></table></form>";
                echo "<p><a href=\"#top\">Top</a>"; 
            }   
        }
    }   
}



?>
```

**Edit 2:**
I try the following for var params:

```
var params = 'querySeq='+querySeq+'&program='+program+'&patientIDarray='+patientIDarray+'&blast_flag='+blast_flag;
```

OR

```
var params = "querySeq=querySeq&program=program&patientIDarray=patientIDarray&blast_flag=blast_flag";
```

with

```
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send(params);
```

But, it does not works! The content in HTML does not changed.
It works only if I assign:

```
var params = "querySeq=querySeq&program=program&patientIDarray=patientIDarray&blast_flag=blast_flag";
```

with

```
xhttp.open("POST", url+"?"+params, true); 
xhttp.send();
```

But, the received parameters are empty.

Any help please.
Thanks,

**Edit 3:**

It's working now. I did not pass parameters from HTML to JS file. Just by pass the parameters with onclick function

```
 onclick=jsFunction(document.getElementById('some parameters').value)
```

Also I use:

```
var params = "querySeq="+querySeq+"&program="+program+"&patientIDarray="+patientIDarray
```

with

```
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhttp.send(params);
```

And it works!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: We can't run that PHP file, we don't have any of the included files. There is also far, far too much of it in the question. You need to include just enough to demonstrate the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This php is successfully run. I was create form tag in the html and in its action I put: "filename.php" and it run successfully but in another url. I just want to display the result in the same url I am working on!

Comment: Again: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, as I said before:  Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Are there errors? Are there warnings? Look at the Network tab. Do you see the request? Is it going to the right URL? Does it have the right data in it? Do you see the response? Does it have the right data in it?

Comment: there is no errors no warning. the network send POST request to the right url with a green circle: http://localhost/webclient/blastresult.php?querySeq=querySeq&program=program&patientIDarray=patientIDarray&blast_flag=blast_flag

Comment: — The data is in the URL. That suggests you haven't implemented my answer.

Comment: I implement it! But, as I said before it does not assign job id and does not create the text file I said before. When I return to my apprach it assign job id and create text file but empty one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104120/discussion-between-reem-and-quentin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> xhttp.open("POST", url+"?"+params, true);
> xhttp.send();
> ```

You are making a POST request, implying that you are looking for the data in `$_POST`, but you have put all the data in the query string. It needs to go in the request body.

```
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send(params);
```

PHP puts data from the query string in `$_GET` and data (with a recognised encoding) from the request body in `$_POST`. Unfortunately, it names the superglobal variables are the request methods where those places are commonly used to store data and not based on where the data actually is.

Comment: @Reem — All else being equal, it should do. You need to provide more information about the problem. Use the developer tools in  your browser. Look at the console. Are there errors? Are there warnings? Look at the Network tab. Do you see the request? Is it going to the right URL? Does it have the right data in it? Do you see the response? Does it have the right data in it? Show us the PHP. How are you trying to read the request data?

Comment: PHP file: $jobid = (empty($_GET['jobid'])) ? '' : $_GET['jobid']; $program = (empty($_POST['program'])) ? '' : $_POST['program']; $querySeq = (empty($_POST['querySeq'])) ? '' : $_POST['querySeq'];

Comment: @Reem — Edit the question, don't shove masses of code in the comments. And show how you generate the output too.

Answer (score 0):

Working GET example:

```
<script>
function jsFunction() {
    var url = "receive.php";
    var params = "querySeq=querySeq&program=program&patientIDarray=patientIDarray&blast_flag=blast_flag";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             // change the content of the div in second tab
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Working POST example:

```
<script>
function jsFunction() {
    var url = "receive.php";
    var params = "querySeq=querySeq&program=program&patientIDarray=patientIDarray&blast_flag=blast_flag";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             // change the content of the div in second tab
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
```

Comment: no parameters at all. I will try using var x = document.getElementsByName("name");

Comment: Well then it ain't gonna help, cause it should receive at least the strings 'query', 'program', etc.

Comment: You can either get or post the data. To get, see my answer, to post, see Quentin his answer